# Glob pattern for a specific regex (REDIS HSCAN)

Tags: regex, redis, glob

I am trying to fetch redis keys/values using a regex but the problem is HSCAN only operates on glob style patterns. I am trying to implement the below regex to glob:

```
/^(?!.*stop#).*tripId#.*$/
```

Which essentially translates to "Key should have substring `tripId#` but not substring `stop#`

Any pointers around this?

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to avoid is returning the entire data-set to your app and the filtering it out on the server side, your best bet would be to use [LUA](https://redis.io/commands/eval) scripting. Simply call HSCAN from the script, and filter out the undesired results before returning them to the calling application.

Another option would be to index items using [RedisSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/). That way, You'll have access to secondary indices a FTS filtering, on top of existing HASHs, which might provide you what you need...